# Socket.io doesn't close connection on linking with reacter-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

As I have understood, Socket.io automatically disconnects on page refresh. However, when using react-router-dom, a disconnect message is not sent to the backend, how would one implement this? I don't think code is needed, however feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the disconnection on window unload event in this way:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = ' ';
});


window.addEventListener('unload', function (e) {
    socket.emit('disconnection message', {data to be sent});
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. However, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you will have to handle it manually in your component using socket.disconnect(). react-router provides a SPA functionality and in that context, the page doesn't actually reload, otherwise you lose the current state and everything starts from scratch.